# CPython/Jython cross-implementation GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, jython

I need to make some GUIs for a Jython application, but would like to minimize translation time should the project switch over to CPython. HTML or XUL are possibilities, but ones that I'd like to avoid. Any ideas on a cross-implementation pythonic GUI toolkit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the discussion here](http://old.nabble.com/wxWidgets-for-Java---Jython---IronPython---td21359279.html), it doesn't look as though there is a single GUI toolkit that can be used across both Jython and CPython. There have been attempts like [wx4j](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wx4j/) (wxWindows for Java) but these are not actively maintained.

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for, but it looks like you're correct.